# What should I learn after learning open and barre chord shapes if I want to learn fingerstyle guitar?

Tags: practice, fingerstyle-guitar

At present I can play most of the chords (I still struggle transitioning from open to barre chord in short amount of time though) and can do basic fingerpicking. However my fingerpicking is very rigid and I can only do tutorials of very slow songs.

I am very new with about 2 months put into the guitar but I want to be as good as Eddie Van Der Meer someday.

What course of action should I do to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: This question (or one like it) was featured in a Wired video: [Polyphia's Tim Henson Answers Guitar Questions From Twitter | Tech Support | WIRED](https://youtu.be/ulchAKGi_Y0?t=523) @8:43

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to consider is the fact that you have several options to choose from and you'll need to choose the one that suits your interest best. Probably the first option to consider is an instructor or mentor that you can freely ask questions and will freely pass along  practice tips and guidance.
Another option is to find instruction sites that interest you on the internet. You'll find some pretty good ones and some others that aren't much help, but the pretty good ones can show you  enough technique to get you moving in the direction you choose for yourself.
A third option is to study techniques from books. There are books that will speak to you on the level that you're currently on, and others that will speak over your head. It will be up to you to find the appropriate ones that speak to your current interests. Libraries are a good place to start. I also recommend used book stores.
The study of Classical guitar has helped many players develop fingerstyle skills. You may find classes at your local community college that focus on beginning classical guitar. You may find these to be helpful.
I'm certain that there are many more ideas and methods you may choose from, but these are the ones that I found most helpful to me. You  are welcome to take any of these ideas and customize them to suit your purposes. And welcome to the website.